# IP address vs. LAN IP address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, c

My modem has an IP address and an internal LAN IP address system.

When I want to send something to my PC from a different location (with the function `send()`), is it possible to give this function both arguments - modem IP address and LAN IP address?

Comment: This sounds like an XY question. What are you hoping to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

If the sender is on the same network as the destination, you can send to the internal (LAN) IP. If the sender is outside the LAN, you have to connect to the external IP (that of the router) after setting up the router to [forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) that particular port to the destination. The exact process for doing that depends entirely on your router. Sending to the external IP has a good chance of working from an internal IP address too, provided that you've set up portforwarding.

Answer (score -1):

If your gonna send the files from a different location then use the IP Address
and not the Internal LAN IP Address, as it is only used if both of your devices are in the same network/internet connection